# Filter linq with list, after the query definition

Tags: linq, list

I'm trying to do a filter on a linq result using a list.

I have a list with customer names:

```
List<string> custList = new List<string> { "customer1", "customer2", "customer3" };
```

then I have my linq code:

```
var userRoles = from u in db.UserRoles.Include(c => c.Customers)
select u;
```

then I want to do the filter using my customer list:

```
userRoles = userRoles.Where(.........);
```

I've already did the filter in the query definition by doing:

```
var userRoles = from u in db.UserRoles.Include(c => c.Customers)
where custList.contain(u.Customers.Name)
select u;
```

But for design purposes I need to do the filter after the query definition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure I understand completely, but you can split it into two queries:

```
var userRoles = from u in db.UserRoles.Include(c => c.Customers)
                select u;
```

Then in some other location:

```
List<string> custList = new List<string> { "customer1", "customer2", "customer3" };

var custRoles = from u in userRoles
                where custList.Contains(u.Customers.Name)
                select u;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var userRoles = from u in db.UserRoles.Include(c => c.Customers)
var someRoles = userRoles.Where(........);
```